# Canonical URLs and trailing slash on root URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, seo, canonical-link

When working with canonical URLs, does a trailing slash make any difference on a root URL?

I put the following canonical tag into my Rails site head:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<%= url_for(:only_path => false) %>" />
```

...to ensure any parameterized URLs resolve to the base URL.

However, when I navigate to `http://www.example.com`, the canonical link shows up *with* a slash at the end:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/" />
```

I know trailing slashes DO matter when a path element is present in the URL, but thought they [didn't matter on root URLs](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/webmasters/BNNot7WgbUg/OXC6yT5inhMJ). However, I then ran into Matt Cutts presentation on canonical tags, where he clearly states that they are considered different URLs:

From http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/canonical-link-tag/ (See slide 3):

> These URLs are all different:
>
> - `www.example.com`
> - `example.com`
> - `www.example.com/`
> - `example.com/`

Can anyone shed some light on what he means?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372402/165673, http://stackoverflow.com/a/2581423/165673

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [Canonical URL for a home page and trailing slashes](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31796/canonical-url-for-a-home-page-and-trailing-slashes)

Answer (score 3):

URLs which point to directory names (often with the expectation that a web server handler will return some sort of 'index'') without a trailing slash are actually invalid. Most web servers will automagically correct these requests with a redirect to the same URL with a trailing slash added.

So behind the scenes, your request for `http://example.com` results in a redirect from the web server to `http://example.com/` which is why you're seeing the surprise trailing slash.

The short answer is that proper URI paths matter everywhere- root directory or not. For a deeper and more ranty answer, take a look at [this page](http://sebastians-pamphlets.com/thou-must-not-steal-the-trailing-slash-from-my-urls/).

Comment: halfway agree with what you're saying. Technically, a root url must contain a trailing slash because it's pointing to the root, and paths cannot be empty. On the other hand, it's pointing to a specific resource (the homepage) and not a directory per se, so in that sense a trailing slash is illogical. As for whether it matters for crawlers, most evidence i've seen so far suggests that for root urls it doesn't.