# Removing trailing slash in the home page url

Tags: .htaccess

I've followed this: [Mode Rewrite; with/without trailing slash on end of url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080495/mode-rewrite-with-without-trailing-slash-on-end-of-url)  solution but it's not working out for my mybb site. I've tried adding it in the top and in the bottom of .htaccess ... but not working.
What could I be missing?

Here is my .htaccess, I've substitute mysite with example.com:

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    # Turn off mod_security filtering.
    SecFilterEngine Off
    # The below probably isn't needed, but better safe than sorry.
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

RedirectMatch 301 ^/archive/index\.php/?(.*)  /$1
    # Some hosts need a RewriteBase specification.
    RewriteBase /
    # Google SEO workaround for search.php highlights:
    # Make this rule the first rewrite rule in your .htaccess!
    RewriteRule ^([^&]*)&(.*)$ http://forum.example.com/$1?$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
    # Google SEO Sitemap:
    RewriteRule ^sitemap-([^./]+)\.xml$ misc.php?google_seo_sitemap=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
    # Google SEO URL Forums:
    RewriteRule ^Forum-([^./]+)$ forumdisplay.php?google_seo_forum=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
    # Google SEO URL Threads:
    RewriteRule ^Thread-([^./]+)$ showthread.php?google_seo_thread=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
    # Google SEO URL Announcements:
    RewriteRule ^Announcement-([^./]+)$ announcements.php?google_seo_announcement=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
    # Google SEO URL Users:
    RewriteRule ^User-([^./]+)$ member.php?action=profile&google_seo_user=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
    # Google SEO URL Calendars:
    RewriteRule ^Calendar-([^./]+)$ calendar.php?google_seo_calendar=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
    # Google SEO URL Events:
    RewriteRule ^Event-([^./]+)$ calendar.php?action=event&google_seo_event=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
    # Google SEO 404:
    ErrorDocument 404 /misc.php?google_seo_error=404
    # Default MyBB Rewrite Rules:
    RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-lastpost\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=lastpost [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-nextnewest\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextnewest [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-nextoldest\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextoldest [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-newpost\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=newpost [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-post-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&pid=$2 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^post-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^announcement-([0-9]+)\.html$ announcements.php?aid=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^user-([0-9]+)\.html$ member.php?action=profile&uid=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?calendar=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=yearview&calendar=$1&year=$2 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)-day-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=dayview&calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3&day=$4 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-week-(n?[0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=weekview&calendar=$1&week=$2 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^event-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=event&eid=$1 [L,QSA]
    <IfModule mod_env.c>
        SetEnv SEO_SUPPORT 1
    </IfModule>
    #Added by Anurag
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript text/css text/html text/xml
</IfModule>


AddType text/javascript .js

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 800000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 800000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 800000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 800000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 800000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 800000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 800000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 800000 seconds"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|css|js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=800000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    Header unset ETag
    Header unset Last-Modified
</IfModule>
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this rule just below `RewriteBase /` line:

```
# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s.+?/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: It isn't working. I've even tried after commenting the second condition.

Comment: That is fully tested rule. FOr which URL it didn't work?

Comment: For http ://forum.example.com/ I've put a space after http here

Comment: There is no trailing slash in that URL. Trailing slash is something like `forum.example.com/forum/`

Comment: But google is considering  forum.example.com/ as duplicate url for forum.example.com. How to handle it?

Comment: That trailing slash is automatically removed by browser: Try entering `http://www.wikipedia.org/` in browser

Comment: You're right: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355328/seo-redirect-homepage-or-root-url-trailing-slash/11372402#11372402