# Wordpress force trailing slash at the end of the main domain page URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, wordpress

After wordpress installation, all the links to the root domain are without slash, even the canonical tag in the home page have like `http://domain.com` instead of `http://domain.com/`.

Is there any option to force wordpress to use the domain name and links with trailing slash at the end instead of without?

I only need it for the main domain, the post url are with trailing slash.

Comment: Is this for SEO? Or something else? From what I currently know, [it shouldn't matter all that much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355328/seo-redirect-homepage-or-root-url-trailing-slash#11372402)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option in Wordpress SEO by Yoast plugin that allows for that.  I think it's the first option under the Permalinks-tab of the plugin.
Success!

Answer (score 0):

You can force a trailing slash at the end of URLs by adding the URL in the Permalink settings of the page or post.

1. Edit the post or page
2. Find the permalink (URL) above the main content (under the title)
3. Edit the end of the permalink and add a forward slash at the end
4. Save changes and publish by hitting the Publish/Update button

Here's a video explainer on what I did to fix this https://www.loom.com/share/8bafbafed75d4bc98c65cd35c36c4f04

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post link- (or video-) only answers but summarize the linked content or its relevant parts a little. A link may become invalid or outdated and in that case, your answer would be useless in the future. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.

Comment: Thanks and apologies. All sorted. I've edited the post and left more detailed instructions above the video.

Answer (score -2):

Under Settings > Permalinks in Custom Structure add '/%postname%/'